# Making a socket connection wait for response after sending command

Tags: java, android, sockets

From the android application, I am creating a socket connection using android services. The idea is that I am connecting to the server when the activity is started and I'am leaving socket connection open for me to reach in other parts of the application.

Now what I'am trying to do is to is that I'am writing a command to the server using buffered writer. After the write I want to implement the check whether the response is already received or not. I'am trying to do this using `while (inStream.available() == 0)` loop. However this is not working. Any ideas how make the app wait for the response of the particular command until processing further code?

Connecting to the socket:

```
    public class connectSocket implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            Log.v("DEV","SocketClass, connectSocket");
            SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(SERVERIP,SERVERPORT);
            command = "authorization";

            try
            {
                socket = new Socket();
                socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
                socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
                socket.connect(socketAddress, 5000);

                if (socket.isConnected())
                {
                    Log.v("DEV","SocketClass successfully connected!");

                    out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    inStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                    int bytesRead;
                    int count = 1;

                    while ((bytesRead = in.read()) > 0 && count != 3)
                    {
                        if (count == 1)
                        {
                            out.write(command + "\r\n");
                            out.flush();
                        }

                        while (inStream.available() == 0)
                        {
                            Log.v("DEV", "sleep "+inStream.available());
                            android.os.SystemClock.sleep(100);
                        }

                        StringTokenizer filterToken = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine(), "^");
                        String temp = filterToken.nextToken();

                        Log.v("DEV", "SocketClass Tokenizer: "+temp);

                        if (temp.equals("cmd_main"))
                        {
                            response = filterToken.nextToken();

                            Intent ret = new Intent();
                            ret.setAction(Testas.RECEIVE_AUTHORIZATION);
                            ret.putExtra("response",response);
                            sendBroadcast(ret);
                            count = 2;
                        }

                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("TCP",e.toString());
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DEV",e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Here I want to wait for the response:

```
    class trackerStatus implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Log.v("DEV", "Socket Class, trackerStatus");

        try
        {
            int bytesRead;
            boolean parse = true;
            command = "command";
            int count = 1;

            while ((bytesRead = in.read()) > 0 && parse)
            {
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    out.write(command + "\r\n");
                    out.flush();
                }

                while (inStream.available() == 0)
                {
                    ////this part is not working
                    Log.v("DEV", "sleep "+inStream.available());
                    android.os.SystemClock.sleep(100);
                }
                Log.v("DEV", "NoSleep "+inStream.available());
                response = in.readLine();

                Log.v("DEV","ReadLine: "+response);

                if (response == null || "".equals(response.trim()))
                {
                    Log.v("DEV","Test Empty");

                    Intent ret = new Intent(Testas.RECEIVE_TRACKER_STATUS);
                    ret.putExtra("status", "OFFLINE");
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(SocketService.this).sendBroadcast(ret);

                    parse = false;
                }

                else
                {
                    StringTokenizer filterToken = new StringTokenizer(response, "^");
                    String temp = filterToken.nextToken();

                    if (temp.equals("trackerinfo"))
                    {
                        StringTokenizer extraFilter = new StringTokenizer(response, "|");
                        temp = extraFilter.nextToken();
                        String[] separate = temp.split(":");

                        if (separate[1].equals(carId))
                        {
                            Intent ret = new Intent();
                            ret.setAction(Testas.RECEIVE_TRACKER_STATUS);
                            ret.putExtra("status", "ONLINE");
                            sendBroadcast(ret);
                            parse = false;
                        }

                    }
                }

                count++;
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation of available(), its perfectly legal for an implementation to always return 0 despite having data available.

Comment: That is why I am asking here. Maybe anyone know how to wait till the data will be available to process next code?

Comment: Specifying what "not working" means would greatly help in answering the question. What difference do you detect between what actually happens and what you need to happen?

Comment: Never mind, it was long time ago - it is neither relevant to me anymore, nor I remember what was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
            while (inStream.available() == 0)
            {
                ////this part is not working
                Log.v("DEV", "sleep "+inStream.available());
                android.os.SystemClock.sleep(100);
            }
            Log.v("DEV", "NoSleep "+inStream.available());
```

Remove all that.

```
            response = in.readLine();
```

Keep that. It will block until data is available or end of stream is detected.